# How to run auto-tests via specific webdriver that I will put in repo instead of webdriver that generated automatically by protractor?

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, protractor, webdriver-manager

I'm using protractor test framework with node.js
with those configuration in protractor_config.js file

```
capabilities: {
        shardTestFiles: yargs.instances > 1,
        maxInstances: yargs.instances || 1,
        browserName: 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
            args: ['--no-sandbox', '--window-size=1920,1080']
        },
    },
    disableChecks: true,
    directConnect: true,
```

Also my version of Chrome is 117.0.5938.149
So when I enter 'npm test' in console
it return me an error: "session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114"

Because webdriver was generated automatically from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/ link

So my question is: where and how I can specify to run my tests via my own chromedriver on Macos instead of that was generated by protractor and located in node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium folder

and that is configuration of config.js file in webdriver-manager:

```
{
  "webdriverVersions": {
    "selenium": "2.53.1",
    "chromedriver": "2.27",
    "maxChromedriver": "77",
    "geckodriver": "v0.13.0",
    "iedriver": "2.53.1",
    "androidsdk": "24.4.1",
    "appium": "1.6.5"
  },
  "cdnUrls": {
    "selenium": "https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/",
    "chromedriver": "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/",
    "geckodriver": "https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/",
    "iedriver": "https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/",
    "androidsdk": "http://dl.google.com/android/"
  }
}
```

and package.json script:

```
"scripts": {
    "format": "gulp format",
    "format-enforce": "gulp format:enforce",
    "gulp": "gulp",
    "jasmine": "jasmine",
    "posttest-e2e": "node ./bin/webdriver-manager shutdown",
    "prepublish": "npm run format-enforce && tsc && gulp copy",
    "pretest": "tsc && gulp copy",
    "pretest-e2e": "npm run pretest && npm run pretest-e2e:update && npm run pretest-e2e:start",
    "pretest-e2e:start": "node ./bin/webdriver-manager start --detach --seleniumPort 4444 --quiet",
    "pretest-e2e:update": "node ./bin/webdriver-manager update",
    "test": "npm run test-unit && npm run test-e2e",
    "test-e2e": "jasmine JASMINE_CONFIG_PATH=e2e_spec/support/headless.json",
    "test-unit": "jasmine",
    "tsc": "tsc"
  },
```

I can't update it to 117 version by command: webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 117.0.5938.149
because this version is not exist in https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/